# Convert string field to decimal in Altova Mapforce

Tags: type-conversion, altova

I have a column with value in string format i.e 00000036, i want to convert it to decimal i.e it should show 36.000000 in the output or let say if i have 00000006 then it should show 6.0000000, The value always needs to be 8 characters

Please let me know how can i achieve this. I used decimal function but it did not help me get the desired result

[image: decimal function]

Answer (score 0):

try format-number and pad-string-right:
[image: 00000036 to 36.00000]

[image: 00000006 to 6.000000]

Comment: Please add a textual description of the solution represented in your pictures. Furhter improvement would be to explain the solution.